# Use js cloneNode to copy <div> template and modify children

Tags: javascript, clonenode

I want to use cloneNode and avoid JQuery to copy a html template in DOM, modify the (nested) children and their ids (and append to an element).

```
  var clone = itm.cloneNode(true); 
  clone.id = 'c' + tid; //replace with new, unique id
  itm = clone.getElementById('childtemplateid');
  ...
```

However, getElementById does not work on clone before it is added to document.
I cannot add the clone to the document before I have changed the ids of the children so a little bit of catch 22...

Is there a state of the art, non-JQuery way do use an html "template" in document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
<div id="test1"><div id="test2"></div></div>

var test3 = document.querySelector("#test1").cloneNode(true);
test3.setAttribute("id", "test3");
test3.querySelector("#test2").setAttribute("id", "test4");
console.log(test3);
```

Please check @ CodePen here:
https://codepen.io/animatedcreativity/pen/8ff7cdb8cffc760c17a03215171faf5c/

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/ar5dbn30/16/

```
var clone = document.getElementById('test').cloneNode(true);
clone.querySelector('.child').innerHTML = "TEST 2"
clone.setAttribute('id', 123)
document.body.appendChild(clone)
```

Changing cloned element child innerHTML and appending to body. The same can be done with any attributes you want for cloned elements or its childs.